# Laravel 5.7 Multilogin SendEmailVerificationNotification error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-notification

I'm new to Laravel. I just created a custom login with laravel 5.7. When I tried to reset password I'm getting this error:

> "Declaration of
>   App\Employee::sendEmailVerificationNotification($token) should be
>   compatible with
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::sendEmailVerificationNotification()"

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Did you solved this issue? or tried mine?

Comment: problem still remains.  I have no idea to do that.  

Comment: If you look at the error correctly, it believes sendEmailVerificationNotification() is a method of User model and not of Employee model, so either you need to call it as User class method or you need to make it Employee class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like this

```
class Employee extends Model implements MustVerifyEmail {
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
    }
}
```

if you want to call it like `Employee::sendEmailVerificationNotification()` and if you want to verify the token you should extend the `VerifyEmail` notification something like

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

class VerifyEmailNotification extends VerifyEmail
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        //verify token
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable);
        }

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'))
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('Please click the button below to verify your email address'))
            ->action(
                Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'),
                $this->verificationUrl($notifiable)
            )
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
    }


    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in Employee model

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmailNotification($token)); // your custom notification
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the same method signature if you want to override it-

You are overriding this method-

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User::sendEmailVerificationNotification()
```

to this-

```
App\Employee::sendEmailVerificationNotification($token)
```

If you notice the difference, you have passed $token in the method while the original method definition does not support that.

Create a different method if you need a different signature from the original method.